# Where can the phrase 给点面子 be used? I was wondering if it has a cultural element that I’m missing

Tags: meaning, usage, saying

我在抖音上看到一部视频说这段话的意思是“Cut me some slack”但是我觉得有点我尚未不知的文化精神，而英语翻译不完全掌握那个感觉。请说明一下这段话是否有什么特殊！谢谢～

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*给点面子* and *Cut me some slack* are very similar.
But I think *给点面子* is slightly more harsh, and implies that the person isn't being respectful enough. that vs. *cut me some lack*, which is a plea for others to go easy on you. it doesn't assume any wrong doing on the part of audience.

Answer (score 1):

给点面子(give me a little respect)  literally means 'give me some face'

It implies the other is being too harsh to the point of being disrespectful. It can be a plea on emotional and/or transactional aspect

Emotional: If you 不給点面子 (not give me even a little respect), I would lose face and my feeling would be hurt, please have some compassion for a fellow man

Transactional: You should consider if I lost face and my feeling is hurt and I have the mean to retaliate (e.g. not agree to your request when it is time you need someone to give you face), it would not be a wise decision for you to carry on refusing my request

In short, asking someone to give you some face is a plea for compassion and/ or a subtle promise that you will return the favor

Example: If you were a manager, an employee of yours made a mistake and you wanted to fire him, but your fellow manager said '给我点面子原諒他一次'(please give me some face and forgive him this time) You can choose to accept or refuse the request base on how you value the relationship between you and this fellow manager.

Answer (score 1):

> When can 给点面子 be used?

When somebody is arrogant and disrespectful.

(I have not grasped the concept of 'face', yet.)

Let's face it:

给点面子: show some respect, be deferential

[baidu](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1618808804155715415&wfr=spider&for=pc)

中国人最爱面子，
Chinese people cherish "face",
也喜欢给别人留面子，
(they) also like to leave others their "face",
遇到一些摆不平的事，
(if they) run into some awkward situations,
说上一句“给个面子”就会有效果。
saying a word to "preserve face" will be very effective.

中国自古有许多关于面子的俗话，
China, since ancient times, has many sayings about "face",
譬如“打人不打脸，
for example, "(if you (verbally)) attack someone don't make them lose face,
说话不揭短”
don't speak of others' shortcomings"
“人活一张脸，树活一张皮”
"People live by face, (like) trees live by bark"

“死要面子活受罪”等等。
"(Even if) you must die, your "face" must live on, accept hardship" etcetera.
(死要面子活受罪，俗语，意思指人太顾及自己的面子，为了脸面而宁愿承受痛苦的折磨。)
("(Even if you) die  (your) "face" must live; accept hardship", a proverb, whose meaning refers to: "people pay much attention to their "face", to preserve "face" they would rather go through painful torment)
面子是中国人很讲究的事。
"Face" is something which Chinese people pay particular attention to.
正因为好面子，
In the name of good "face",
所以做事一般都点到为止，
therefore, (when they) handle (their) affairs, (they always) somewhat cautious,
彼此不伤和气，
(they try) not to hurt each other's feelings,
办事也事半功倍。
doing things then is easier.
人与人相处很讲究留面子，
(In) interpersonal relations, (the Chinese) pay particular attention to "face",
留了面子可能给以后有求于人的时候留下成功的机会。
Preserving face may, later, when you require something, be advantageous.
中国人在交往的时候，
When Chinese people interact,
尤其是冲突和矛盾的时候，
especially when there is a conflict or contradiction,
最经常说的一句话就是“给了面子”。
the most frequently heard phrase is "preserve face".
如果你不给面子，
If you are not deferential,
那必然会两败俱伤，
(it is) inevitable that both sides will suffer,
大家不欢而散，
both will part on bad terms,
得不偿失。
(you will) lose more than you gain.
如果给了面子，
If you keep "face",
就相当于给别人一个下台阶，
(that is) the same as giving the other person an (honourable) way out,
与人方便自己方便。
and, by helping others, you may actually also help yourself.
“面子”对中国人意义挺大，
"Face" means a great deal to Chinese people,
比如一个人做一件事做的很周到，
For example, (if) someone does something very thoughtfully,
很圆满，
very satisfactorily,
别人夸赞的时候，
when others praise this person,
他就会觉得很有面子。
he will feel greatly honoured.
如果没做好，
However, if (he has not) done a good job,
别人议论的时候，
when others comment,
他就会觉得很没面子。
he will feel dishonoured.
“面子”在中国人心里就是地位和能力的代名词。
"Face" for the Chinese is synonymous with ability.
“面子”这种中国人特有的表达方式，
"Face" this  archetypal Chinese expression,
外国人一时半会儿是弄不明白的。
foreigners, (at least) for a while, cannot make head nor tail of "face".